# Parsing "the shortest route to take in a reasonably sized problem"

Tags: parsing

This is the context:

> The traveling salesman problem must be seen as a limitation of the human ability to know. There is no way that one can possibly know the shortest route to **take in** a reasonably sized problem.

Can anyone tell me what's the meaning of taking in? does it mean like understanding or comprehending the problem?

Comment: If I add a comma to the sentence you will see "take" and "in" are separated. "There is no way that one can possibly know the shortest route to take, in a reasonably sized problem." This is about the difficulty in solving a [classic computing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *take in*. It is *the shortest route to take* and *in a reasonably sized problem* as **separate phrase**s. The Travelling Salesmen Problem is about finding the shortest route to take, and the statement is saying that, where you have a reasonably sized instance of the problem, no person can know the shortest route.